# Problem creating more than one Rails app using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

I properly installed MongoDB and got it running on my OSX.  The first app I created using MongDB and Rails3 was titled 'todo".  Per the
instructions on railscasts, I created a file (config/initilializers/
mongo.rb) and added this line:

```
MongoMapper.database = "todo-
#{Rails.env}"
```

Presumably, this created the files that appeared in my /data/db/ file entitled "todo-
development".  When I used the generate command in Rails to create the
models, the data was correctly stored in this file.  All good, up to this
point.

The problem now is that I can't seem to create NEW files in the /data/db file when
I create new apps with Rails. (I think) the data file should be
created from the initializer file (ex:

```
MongoMapper.database = "newproject-
#{Rails.env}"
```

that I add to each new app. But it
is not.

Here's my gemfIle (that worked with my first app!:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'mongo', '1.0'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta4'
gem "mongo_mapper"
gem 'bson_ext', '1.0'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out with the help Kristian Mandrup in a Google Group.  Thanks Kristian. I needed to uncomment the config.generator in my application.rb file and change orm from active_record to mongo_mapper.  (btw, the error I was getting before when trying to run the generator was ""No value provided for required options '--orm'.")

More here: http://www.viget.com/extend/rails-3-generators-hooks/

For what it's worth, I'm including the entire process that I needed to take in order to get MongoDB and Rails 3 working together properly.

---

Install MongoDB on OSX

```
$ sudo port install mongodb
```

Create a data directory:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Set permissions for data directory:

```
$sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

Start Mongo in Terminal:

```
$ mongod run
```

Visit local host to verify that MongoDB is running:

```
http://localhost:28017/
```

Create new project with Rails 3:

```
$ rails new projectname --skip-activerecord
```

Add this to the gemfile:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'mongo', '1.0'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta4'
gem "mongo_mapper"
gem 'bson_ext', '1.0'
```

uncomment out (and modify) these lines in application.rb file:

```
config.generators do |g|
    g.orm :mongo_mapper
end
```

Create config/initializer/mongo.rb file:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "projectname-#{Rails.env}"
```

Create a lib/tasks/mongo.rake file:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare do # Stub out for MongoDB
    end
  end
end
```

Install gems:

```
$bundle install
```

Create first model:

```
$rails generate scaffold Product name:string --skip-migration
```

Create models/product.rb file:

```
class Product
 include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name, string
end
```